# mule anypoint studio class not found exception

Tags: mule, mule-studio

If I run the application in server, which is working fine, but If i run application in anypoint studio doesn't run. Here is the error message for loading oracle driver.

error message:

```
2015-02-04 11:18:34 WARN  DriverManagerDataSource:107 - Could not load driverClass oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

I have placed all jdbc and other jars under studio->project->properties->libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the Studio's classloading policies. The workaround is to copy the JDBC Driver .jar to ${studio.home}/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.${mule.version}.ee_${mule.version}.${release.date}/mule/lib/user

Comment: This is wrong way. It will work in this particluar Studio insatllaion and not in expoerted app or another Studio. The right way - put JDBC jar what you are using into any acessible place and put this place to the classpath. Easiest way - put it to lib folder then right click and add to classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there actually that's kind of a hack :P though it works.

The more proper way to deal with this is, when coding your application (that's why one should use Mule Studio), to place the jars like drivers in a particular folder, like a /lib in the root of you project.

Then add these jars to the classpath. 
I know what you did is the way it should be done when running on Mule stand alone in order to share such jars but try this one if you can ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. As the application runtime fails to locate the jdbc driver jar in classpath So It is unable to load the same.

the simple and easiest way to handle this error is just put your lib folder containing the ojdbc jar file inside the app resource (src/main/app) of the project. During the building of project it will automatically be place in classpath.

I have tried the same approach and It works for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed the problem was removing the .classpath / .project files from my project root folder. I re-imported the project and then I saw a bin folder created. I removed this bin folder then right-click on the project -> Refresh and then Run As -> Mule Application.